# Should the Model or ViewModel handle lazy loading of a Model's properties?

Tags: c#, mvvm, lazy-loading

Lets say I have a `ConsumerModel`. `ConsumerModel` has many Model properties, and one is a list of `AddressModel`. I want this Address property to be lazy loaded because it is not used in everywhere that the ConsumerModel is. It is only used in the `AddressViewModel` which displays and allows changes to a Consumer's Addresses.

Who takes care of loading the AddressModels, the `ConsumerModel` or the `AddressViewModel`?

Or is there an alternate design that is suggested for this type of thing, such as detaching the list of Addreses from the Consumer and handling them as a separate property from within the `AddressViewModel`?

```
public class ConsumerModel : IModel
{
    private List<AddressModel> _addresses;

    public List<AddressModel> Addresses
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It belongs in the model. The point of using the ViewModel pattern is to remove these kinds of decisions from the View in the first place. The model is responsible for all data collection, organization and management. The ViewModel is only responsible for making sure that what the model contains gets output to the UI. While it seems like a good idea to put this in ViewModel, if the spec changes next week and suddenly you need that address in a different ViewModel (for whatever reason), you will have broken the pattern and you'll be scrambling to make it up.

Comment: Part of why I am not sure is because the Model library does not contain a reference to the WCF service to get data. Only the ViewModel library does. If I add the data instantiation to the Model then I also have to start adding references to the WCF services to that library. The model library was intentionally left without a reference to the WCF service because it is used inside the WCF service and adding that reference would create a circular reference

Comment: @Rachel - I have always used a 3rd library specifically for data access. Instead of using a reference in the ViewModel, I use a reference to my DataLibrary (which holds/controls access to the web service). The DataLibrary contains my custom data access objects which are then accessible to both the ViewModel and the Model independently.

Comment: Yeah I actually use a separate data access library too, however I was trying to simplify the problem. So in your case, both your ViewModel and Model have access to get data? The Model for getting data and the VM for saving/adding/deleting?

Comment: @Rachel - It depends on the project. Usually only the Model has access to the data layer because the ViewModel is supposed to be using the Model layer to perform all of its functions. However, a reference to a library costs nothing, and in the long run there are advantages to having direct data access from the ViewModel. Be careful of potential circular references though. If you bypass the Model layer and go with direct access, you may end up improperly populating/usinga model object.

Comment: @Joel. +1 for a smoking hot answer and then some. Cheers

Comment: @Joel - Thank you for taking the time to explain that, it is making more sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

If the Addresses property belongs on the ConsumerModel, then the ConsumerModel must be responsible for loading it. (Anything else is breaking encapsulation / some sort of design principle - I'm lax on my terminology... it just feels wrong damnit!)

However, if the Addresses list is only used on AddressViewModel, then maybe there's a case for moving the property to that ViewModel, and having it handle the loading.